# How can I populate empty rows in Excel using VBA programming?

Tags: vba, excel, drop-down-menu, auto-populate

I have created a drop-down menu and am trying to use VBA so that when certain menu items are selected, empty rows with populate beneath the menu item. The number of empty rows will be dependent on the menu item chosen.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried so far? We're much more here to help with specific questions of the form "I tried X, but it did not do what I expect and instead resulted in an error!" accompanied by a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Try use "change" activeX event, which can be added to your sheet code where your comboBox are in.

i.e:

[image: Sheet Event]

Something like this:

```
Private Sub comboBoxName_change()

    Select case comboBoxName.list(comboBoxName.listIndex)

    case "a"
    'your code to populate rows

    case "b"
    'your code to populate rows

    case "c"
    'your code to populate rows

    case [...]

    end Select

end sub
```